# Anatomically Correct Kampe

Tags: mythical-creatures, anatomy, dragons, humanoid, anatomically-correct

The Kampe is a great horrid dragon with a very unique form

They have a roughly humanoid shape. Above the shoulders is a single great stem-neck from which 51 heads (one human, 50 bestial) grow. The human head is monstrous, with serpentine hair. The arms are human-like. They are winged, and have a giant scorpion set into their back, with claws above the shoulders, legs coming out of the chest, and a long tail beyond the legs. The rest of the torso is human-like. The legs are similar to snakes, and divide into yet more snakes to form the feet. All of the heads are functional and capable of thinking and eating

**How could this unique anatomy fit together inside?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Heads

There are not many ways for a neck to support 51 heads. One of these ways would involve a rather unique set-up: The neck would be supported by a set of scales, as in echinoderms, which would each support a single animal head. Each skul would be fused directly onto its scale by the occipital bone, and have a window underneath through which the pharynx will pass into the main pharynx which goes down the middle of the neck. Each brain will also be connected to a cylindrical 'nerve net' around the neck. The human head will be placed at the top of this neck, with a similar scale that faces upwards

A similar scale system, with a similar nerve net, could be placed in the humanoid skull replacing the parietal bones. The snakes would articulate with the scales at the spine, rather than the occiput, so that they can move. These snakes would need complete digestive tracts at least up to the stomach, with only a thin small intestine going through into the braincase. These intestines will flow along the meninges, coming together, until they empty through a foramen in the sphenoid into the pharynx. These snakes would only need the digestive and nervous organs, as the torso's organs woul provide the other needs

## Wings

The wings, due to the imposition of the scorpion, will need special considerations. The only real way to have them is if they were mostly non-functional. Specifically, you would have a tetrapodal wing attached to the back of the scapula, under the trapezius. It would have a few weak muscles similarly to the arms, but much smaller. The wing structure itself will have to be light, so that it could be moved around easily with its weaker muscles

## Scorpion

The scorpion will provide many issues for their anatomy, but they can be solved. Firstly, the claws: These could be attached to the scapulae above of the trapezius, with the scorpion muscles deep to the humanoid ones. The legs could be articulated and muscled on the ribs, behind the upper part of the external obliques. The tail would be easy to append to the end of the spine

On the internal structures: The viscera would likely have to be humanoid (or at least tetrapodal) to support this great creature, but it could still have scorpion-like additions. For example, it could include a scorpion's heart replacing the inferior vena cava, a ventral nerve cord, and a branch of the intestine going through the tail. There could also be genital openings and extra lungs in the stomach, if there is space

## Legs/Feet

Snakes can be pretty strong, and there are many examples of snakes that can move upright (though not quite in the same orientation as here). With the added balancing of the humanoid parts, it should be easy for these snake-legs to walk. On the specifics of the connection, the simplest method would be for the proximal vertebrae of the legs to end in a humanoid femur head, so that it may easily fit in a regular humanoid pelvis

The feet could be formed similarly to the neck, but with a large flat plate like an elephant's foot at the end replacing the main head. The scales and snakes would be like that of the skull. The organs that process the snake's food can simply be placed within the snake bodies, either in the feet, the legs, or across both. These digestive tracts would internally empty into the humanoid rectum